# Text is displayed in the background of a indeterminate progress bar in an AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, android-layout, progress-bar, autocompletetextview

I have an `AutoCompleteTextView` and an indeterminate progress bar in a relative layout.
The problem I now have is that if text displayed is long enough, it is put in the background of the progress bar.

How can I prevent this?

This is the relevant xml code:

```
  <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/AddressContainer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/SearchBtn"

     >

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/SearchField"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:lines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        >
    </AutoCompleteTextView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="@style/Widget.ProgressBar.Medium"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[Link to an image showing the problem](http://s12.postimage.org/m3pjd2unx/screenshot_1333523666888.png)

Comment: what you want to do, can you be more specific and paste some code and the xml file you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this changes so the `AutoCompleteTextView` and ProgressBar` don't overlap:

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/AddressContainer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/SearchBtn"
     >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="@style/Widget.ProgressBar.Medium"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
         />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/SearchField"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/progressBar1"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:lines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        >
    </AutoCompleteTextView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Edit:

Now I've seen that picture, if you want the text to not go under the `ProgressBar` simply add some right padding to your `AutoCompleteTextView` like:

```
android:paddingRight="55dp">
```